# xAPI verb not showing in the ADL Public statement viewer

Tags: tin-can-api

This is part of the last question that I posted. The code below sends the statement but when I view the record in the ADL statement viewer the verb is not showing. Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong on the verb line? Thank you.

```
function init()
        {

var stmt = new ADL.XAPIStatement(
    'mailto:menken.john@gmail.com',
    'http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/launched',
    'http://vwf.adlnet.gov/xapi/virtual_world_sandbox'
);

            ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({
                'endpoint': 'https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/',
                'user': 'xapi-tools',
                'password': 'xapi-tools',
                'auth': 'xapi-tools'
            });

            ADL.XAPIWrapper.sendStatement(stmt);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `verb` object does not contain a `display` property including a human readable version of the verb (which is not required so your statement is valid), the ADL statement viewer doesn't appear to have a fallback (such as to the `id`).